# Возможно ли как то законсервировать состояние виндовс 10 в определенный момент?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Например установил чистый виндовс, поставил все необходимые драйверы, программы например фотошоп VS и тд. И вот это состояние как то сохранить. Что бы в случае когда нужно переустановить виндовс начинать не с нуля а с готовой настроенной системы.

Подходит ли для этого точка восстановления виндовс? Вроде как пишут что она сохраняет только состояние самой ОС но не программ.

Comment: *Подходит ли для этого точка восстановления виндовс?* Не подходит. *Возможно ли как то законсервировать состояние виндовс в определенный момент?* Либо делаете бэкап системы штатными средствами (но для восстановления нужна рабочая ОС) либо снимаете образ системного диска любой сторонней программой - хоть dd (сохраняться и восстанавливаться надо с лив-сидюка или флешки)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без изменения конфигурации системы, то можно сделать слепок диска программой Acronis True Image

Если потом систему нужно будет устанавливать компьютеры с другой конфигурацией, то предварительно необходимо выполнить команду sysprep

Answer (score 0):

Windows есть встроенная система бэкапа в разделе архивирования, создается полный бэкап системы по выбору и диск восстановления, потом можно восстановить ОС с диска либо с помощью системы восстановления